# Task.WhenAll doesn't resume

Tags: c#, async-await, task, tpl-dataflow

Below code is simplified version what i am trying to do. The code supposed to reach Console.ReadKey() line very quickly but it never happens. Task.WhenAll never resume next line. What is wrong on the code ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoWorkAsync().Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        var block = new ActionBlock<Job>(async (task) =>
        {
            await task.DoAsync();
        });
        var jobs = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(i => new Job());
        foreach (var job in jobs)
        {
            await block.SendAsync(job);
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(jobs.Select(c => c.Completion));
    }

    public class Job
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        public Task<bool> Completion { get { return completionSource.Task; } }
        public async Task DoAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            completionSource.SetResult(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will help.

```
var jobs = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(i => new Job()).ToList();
```

It happens because of multiple enumeration of `jobs`

In this line `await Task.WhenAll(jobs.Select(c => c.Completion));` you are waiting for new jobs, which are not send to block.

Comment: You are right. I never thought that i will get new items whenever iterate given IEnumerable. It is very unexpected to me.

Comment: It is unfortunate that they haven't imitated ReSharper's multiple enumeration warning yet. It protects you from precisely this mistake.